# Add icon to custom view header VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

am making an extension for VsCode and am trying to add icons to the header of my custom view instead of the containers inside as shown in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uveq3.png).

Thanks.

Comment: You have to add menu entries to the package.json

Comment: can you please tell me which entries should I use ? tried the "view/title" still not working

Comment: see last example in paragraph https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#updating-tree-view-content